# How can I dynamically import npm modules in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

Not sure if this requires Lazy.load and Suspense.

Essentially I have a Mapbox Component that I would like to dynamically import the npm modules then load the component.

```
const ReactMapboxGl = require('react-mapbox-gl');
const Map = ReactMapboxGl.Map({
    accessToken: mapboxAccessToken,
    interactive: false
});
```

Comment: I dont know if its supported to dynamically import modules alone. But you can Dynamic import them when you import the Components in which they are imported as normal

Comment: Not sure what you mean by " you can Dynamic import them when you import the Components in which they are imported as normal".


The above code belongs inside the mapbox component.

`import * as React from 'react';
import { mapboxAccessToken } from '../../../config';

const ReactMapboxGl = require('react-mapbox-gl');
const Map = ReactMapboxGl.Map({
 accessToken: mapboxAccessToken,
 interactive: false
});

Mapbox extends React.Component<IMapboxProps, any> {
 render() {
  return <Mapbox ....
 }
}`